# ¿Cómo filtrar objetos que no cumplen con las condiciones pero sin tomar en cuenta los filtros vacíos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una función que debe permitir filtar los usuarios que se van a cargar a una lista, el problema es que los filtros (parámetros) deben ser opcionales. No encontré la forma de ignorar los filtros con valor `None`. El siguiente código es una situación parecida a la que deseo realizar, para que puedan ejecutar y probar.

```py
def get_participants(name=None, email=None, rol=None):
    # obtengo el listado
    trs = [
        {'name': 'ramon juanes', 'email': 'ugand@gmail.com', 'rol': 'jefe'},
        {'name': 'lara galaz',   'email': 'rabon@gmail.com', 'rol': 'trabajador'},
        {'name': 'samuel adobe', 'email': 'minum@gmail.com', 'rol': 'trabajador'},
        {'name': 'juan carlos',  'email': 'lunes@gmail.com', 'rol': 'supervisor'},
    ]
    participants = []
    for tr in trs:
        user = Participant(tr)
        # momento del filtro
        # si un filtro es None produce un TypeError
        # if name in user.name and email in user.name and rol in user.rol:
        #     participants.append(user)

        # si un filtro es None no toma en cuenta al resto de los campos
        # if (name and name in user.name) and (email and email in user.name) and (rol and rol in user.rol):
        #    participants.append(user)

        # este caso no tiene sentido tomarlo debido al siguiente resultado:
        # len(get_participants(name='lara', email='minum')) -> 2, pero debería ser 0, ya que no esta en listado
        # if (name and name in user.name) or (email and email in user.name) or (rol and rol in user.rol):
        #   participants.append(user)
    return participants
```

```py
class Participant:
    def __init__(self, tr):
        self.name = tr['name']
        self.email = tr['email']
        self.rol = tr['rol']
```

En el código original:

```py
def get_participants(self, subject_id, name=None, email=None, rol=None):
    self.open_with_session(f'https://www.page.com/user/index.php?id={subject_id}')
    trs = self.page.select('#participants tbody tr')
    participants = []
    for tr in trs:
        user = Participant(tr)
        # TypeError cuando name, email o rol es None
        if name in user.name and email in user.name and rol in user.rol:
            participants.append(user)
    return participants
```

```py
class Participant:
    def __init__(self, tr):
        self.name = tr.select_one('.c1').text.lower()
        self.email = tr.select_one('.c2').text.lower()
        self.rol = tr.select_one('.c3').text.strip().lower()
```

He probado con usar el argumento `**kwargs` pero eso implicaría convertir mis objetos `Participant` en diccionarios, y utilizar un `for` con un `break`, lo cual le quita cierta elegancia al código:

```py
def get_participants(**kwargs):
    # obtengo el listado
    trs = [
        {'name': 'ramon juanes', 'email': 'ugand@gmail.com', 'rol': 'jefe'},
        {'name': 'lara galaz',   'email': 'rabon@gmail.com', 'rol': 'trabajador'},
        {'name': 'samuel adobe', 'email': 'minum@gmail.com', 'rol': 'trabajador'},
        {'name': 'juan carlos',  'email': 'lunes@gmail.com', 'rol': 'supervisor'},
    ]
    participants = []
    for tr in trs:
        user = {
            'name': tr['name'], # tr.select_one('.c1').text.lower()
            'email': tr['email'], # tr.select_one('.c2').text.lower()
            'rol': tr['rol'], # tr.select_one('.c3').text.strip().lower()
        }
        append = True
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            if not kwargs[key] in user[key]:
                append = False
                break
        if append:
           participants.append(user)
    return participants
```

Este código funciona, pero quisiera saber si hay una forma más simple de realizar esta tarea y sin tener que usar diccionarios (remplazando a mis objetos `Participant`).

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para filtrar los participantes se puede tener en cuenta dos condiciones:

- Cada parámetro correspondiente a un atributo de *Participant* es *None*, ó
  está incluido en él.
- La condición anterior se debe cumplir simulteaneamente con todos los parámetros.

Entonces podemos usar las siguientes condiciones:

```
name_match = (name is None) or (name in user.name)
email_match = (email is None) or (email in user.email)
rol_match = (rol is None) or (rol in user.rol)

if name_match and email_match and rol_match:
    participants.append(user)
```

Nota que por cortocircuito si *name* es *None*, `name in user.name` no se evalua
y por lo tanto no tira una excepción.

Y para ejemplificar los posibles casos, una especie de "tabla de verdad" de
*name_match*:

```
name  | user.name | name is None | name in user.name | (name is None)
      |           |              |                   | or (name in user.name)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
None  | "asd"     |    True      |        -          |    True
"as"  | "asd"     |    False     |      True         |    True
"asd" | "12345"   |    False     |      False        |    False
```

Comment: a modo de mejorar el código un poco más, el `name is None` es remplazable por `not name`